# Shear strain of a fluid element

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, continuum-mechanics

I am going through the derivation of the shear strain rate formula for a fluid element and ran into a point of confusion. In the figure below, the change in angle that occurs as the line segment $BC$ deforms into $B'C'$ is equal to:
$$\text{d}\alpha\approx \tan(\text{d}\alpha)=\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\text{d}x\text{d}t}{\text{d}x+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\text{d}x\text{d}t}$$.

[image: 1]

Everything up to this point makes perfect sense to me. But all of the derivations I have found takes an additional step of approximating that $\text{d}x+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\text{d}x\text{d}t=\text{d}x$, simplifying the above equation to:
$$\text{d}\alpha=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\text{d}t$$
or equivalently,
$$\frac{\text{d}\alpha}{\text{d}t}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

What exactly is it that allows us to make the simplification $\text{d}x+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\text{d}x\text{d}t=\text{d}x$? I haven't found a source that addresses this explicitly and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that they are neglecting that term because it is of second order, that is

$$ \mathrm{d}x \gg \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t\, .$$

So, you shouldn't have an equality there but an approximately equal sign.